# Symbol not found: _ap_lua_init_mutex when loading mod_lua

Tags: apache, mod-lua

I have Apache httpd server installed via Homebrew. I tried compiling `mod_lua` by running

```
apxs -i -a -c mod_lua.c
```

But httpd is failing to start with error

> Cannot load /usr/local/lib/httpd/modules/mod_lua.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/lib/httpd/modules/mod_lua.so, 10): Symbol not found:
>   _ap_lua_init_mutex\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/httpd/modules/mod_lua.so\n  Expected in: flat
>   namespace\n in /usr/local/lib/httpd/modules/mod_lua.so

What does the above error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by building the module with

```
apxs -I/usr/local/include/lua5.3 -i -a -c mod_lua.c lua_*.c -lm  -llua
```